# ListView Data Won't Refresh in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, listview

I am trying to load data into a ListView in WPF using a Stored Procedure and Entity Framework. When I first load the User Control the ListView loads the data just fine. I then call the same code to refresh the data and I can see through debugging that the ListItems count changes but the data on the front end screen does not update.

XAML

```
<ListView Name="DocsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Documents" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Documents}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code Behind

```
public void LoadDocs()
{
    Context _Context = new Context();
    DocsListView.ItemsSource = null;
    DocsListView.ItemsSource = _Context.SP_GetDocuments(1).ToList();
    _Context = null;
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I'm using VS2012, .Net 4.5, and EF 5.0.

Comment: you call the same LoadDocs method to refresh the data?

Comment: Yes, I call LoadDocs method to refresh the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I´m not sure whats causing the Problem, generally I would recommend to use a DependencyProperty!

But you could try to refresh the ListView like that:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DocsListView.ItemsSource);
view.Refresh();
```

If this is going to be a bigger Project I strongly recommend to have a look at the MVVM DesignPattern!

[WPF and MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) play well together. There are nice Libraries you can use like [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

Also you should have a look at the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

XAML-Code (Don´t forget to set the DataContext)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="DocsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Documents" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Documents}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# Code-Behind (ObservableCollection refreshes the UI automatically if a Item gets added or deleted):

```
public ObservableCollection<YourEntity> Data
{
     get { return (ObservableCollection<YourEntity>)GetValue(DataProperty); }
     set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(ObservableCollection<YourEntity>), typeof(MainWindow), null);

public void LoadDocs()
{
     Context _Context = new Context();
     if(Data == null)
     {
         Data = new ObservableCollection<YourEntity>();
     }
     else
     {
         Data.Clear();
     }
     foreach(var doc in _Context.SP_GetDocuments(1).ToList())
     {
         Data.Add(doc);
     }
     _Context = null;
}
```

Comment: Data.Clear is null when I get to that line of code. Am I missing where to set it? (MVVM would be ideal but this is a small app)

Comment: now it should work, of course you have to initialize the Data Property first! ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But I'm still having the same problem. ListView loads perfect the first time, but calling the exact same code does not refresh the List. I'm even trying DocsListView.Items.Refresh() and the UI doesn't update. :(

Comment: are you sure that you are getting different Items on the second call? maybe SP_GetDocuments always returns the same result! Can you share code for this Method

Comment: I just figured it out! I was incorrectly creating another instance of the User Control from the MainWindow and calling the method in the wrong instance of the User Control!

Comment: aaah OK :-) I´m glad you found the Error, but still I would recommend you to stick with dependency Properties or to use the MVVM Pattern ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am going to use the code you suggested above as it's working perfectly now and future apps we will be using MVVM for sure.